# Determine if iOS or Android via AWS Cloudfront

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, user-agent, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using AWS Cloudfront as my CDN and they seem to only have basic mobile detection.

In other words, they give me the header `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` (which is either true or false) but there is no option to get the full useragent.

**How can I tell if the mobile is iOS or Android?**

Comment: Did you take a loot at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enhanced-cloudfront-customization/ ? I think you need to whitelist the User Agent header for it to work.

Comment: @EugenDimboiu thanks I'll take a look!

Comment: @AmyNeville Did this resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `CloudFront-Is-Android-Viewer` and `CloudFront-Is-IOS-Viewer` headers. The rest of the headers you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html)